# How to aggregate based on condition?

Tags: r

I'm learning R. I would aggregate data which looks like this:

```
ID   Score  Elements
231  123    "a,b,c"
132  123    "b,c,d"
321  123    "e"
645  123    "d, f"
321  200    "foo,bar,baz"
```

**I would like to combine all rows where an element matches.** The above would result in 3 rows with only the rows 1,2,3 combining because of a shared b/c and d. It's possible to have hundreds of rows which must be combined, or identical rows.

Output should be:

```
Score  Elements
123    "a,b,c,d,f"
123    "e"
200    "foo,bar,baz"
```

I'm currently using `aggregate` on the Score column because this is *almost* a good group identifier, however in some corner cases there are groups with the same score ('e' in the above). I'm using a custom combiner function to combine the Score values into string vectors. My current code is:

```
customCombiner <- function(foo) {
    return(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(as.vector(foo), collapse = ","),','))))
}
result = aggregate(
    myDataFrame$Elements,
    by=list(score=myDataFrame$score),
    customCombiner
)
```

Is it possible to aggregate rows but first check if they should be aggregated? Or a different solution to my problem?

Comment: Is your aggregation transitive, and does it require updating? That is, as in your example, if row A has elements `"a,b,c"` and row B has elements `"b,c,d"`, would you want the `"d"` appended to row A's elements? And if another row, row C has element `"d"` would it also get aggregated with row A, via row B?

Comment: @Gregor Yes. Sorry, I should have made it clearer. At the end each element ends up in a single row. Sometimes the result is only a single row because everything gets combined. I don't know what you mean by updating? There's no new data being added or changes being made.

Comment: By "updating", I mean do you want the `Elements` columns to have additional elements appended to them. In your example, after the first two rows are are combined, is the `Elements` entry for that row as `"a,b,c,d"`? A *slightly* more complicated example (add a row to your input like Row C from my first comment) as well as *explicitly written-out desired output* would make your question much clearer. You could also simplify the example to use `sum` to combine the scores, and mention that you want it to be generalizable to a custom combining function.

Comment: Example output, what a great idea! I've added some. Yes, the final result contains all the elements which are merged together. In any instance where a combination happens the scores should be identical. But there are times where combination should not happen and scores are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a tricky problem; you will need to find the components of an undirected graph, where each row of your data is a node, and with edges between them if they have any overlap of elements.

First, you should get you data cleaned up using `strsplit()`, which will give you a list of sets, similar to this:

```
m <- list(c('a','b','c'), c('b','c','d'), 'e', c('d', 'f'), c('foo','baz','bar'))
```

Then, you can calculate an adjacency matrix using `outer` and `intersect`:

```
adj <- outer(m,m,Vectorize(function(x,y) length(intersect(x,y))))
```

which is this matrix:

```
> adj
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    0    0    0
[2,]    2    3    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    2    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    3
```

Then, using the `igraph` package, convert the matrix to a graph and extract the components:

```
cmp <- components(graph.adjacency(adj))
```

`cmp$membership` is the assignment of each node to a component:

```
> cmp$membership
[1] 1 1 2 1 3
```

You can eg find all the elements of a component using `tapply`:

```
> tapply(m, cmp$membership, Reduce, f=union)
$`1`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f"

$`2`
[1] "e"

$`3`
[1] "foo" "baz" "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer I am looking for. I've not accepted it because I want to get it working first. Do you have any advice on linking up the Score value of each group to the final groupings? After calling tapply they are just called `\`1\``, `\`2\``, `\`3\`` with no way to link back to the score value.

Comment: The 1,2,3 is the component index in `cmp$membership`. You should be able to aggregate score by `cmp$membership`; then you can either sort and cbind, or do a merge.